# Custom input validator does not display an error as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have simplified my app just to show the problem I am having with a custom validator.

You can see the app code on StackBlitz:
[validator](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9dizhw?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

My validator `cannotContainSpace` is definitely called by the framework because I can set a breakpoint on it but the message from the HTML template.

> Password can not contain space.

is not displayed as I would expect.

In other words, when I enter some word with the space and press the `Login` button I would expect the error:

> Password can not contain space.

to be displayed in the page content, but no error is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from here:

```js
password: [
  '',
  Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), this.cannotContainSpace,
],
```

which you should wrap multiple Validators into an array such:

```js
password: [
    '',
    [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), this.cannotContainSpace],
],
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yse5mb?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

---

**References**

[Adding custom validators to reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-custom-validators-to-reactive-forms)